# PCLCrypto asymmetric encryption failing with leading zero padding public key

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, pcl-crypto

Running the following code fails. When I import the public key one of the RSA parameters seems to get padded with a leading zero, causing the `publickKey` to be 520 bits instead of the 512 bits of the `privateKey`.

```
public static void Test()
{
    var algorithm = WinRTCrypto.AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithm.RsaPkcs1);
    ICryptographicKey privateKey = algorithm.CreateKeyPair(512);
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = privateKey.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);
    ICryptographicKey publicKey = algorithm.ImportPublicKey(publickKeyBytes, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);

    var encryptedValue = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));
    var decryptedValue = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(privateKey, encryptedValue);
}
```

The problem seems to be this line:

```
algorithm.ImportPublicKey(publickKeyBytes, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.X509SubjectPublicKeyInfo);
```

The `publicKeyBytes` seems right. It works against another service that uses it to encrypt some data that I can succesfully decrypt. This issue is when i try to create some dummy encrypted data for unit testing.

Im running this code in a Portable Class Library using .Net Framework 4.5.

The above code throws at the line where it try's to decrypt, a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException`with the following message:

> The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 64
>   bytes.

The following assert fails:

```
Assert.Equals(privateKey.KeySize, publicKey.KeySize)
```

Doing the following removeing the padded zero from the Modulus fix the public key and everything works fine.

```
RSAParameters rsaPublicParameters = publicKey.ExportParameters(false);
rsaPublicParameters.Modulus = rsaPublicParameters.Modulus.Skip(1).ToArray();
ICryptographicKey workingPublicKey = algorithm.ImportParameters(rsaPublicParameters);
```

Is this a bug in PCLCrypto or am I using it wrong.

Comment: "...fails...". You must be specific about how it fails. The external/internal representation of big integers should not necessarily concern you. It is common to represent a big integer whose high-order byte is greater > 127 with a leading zero byte.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Sorry was a bit fast. It fails when i try to decrypt the encrypted data. The problem is the public key gets length 520 and the private key has length 512. Ill update the question with the exception thrown.

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory. Again, the 520 versus 512 is not the issue.

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you please explain it to me then? Because I do not understand it. If I from a private key 512 bit key, export the public key blob in X509 format. Why should the key then grow by 1 byte, to 520 bits when imported and used for encryption? Causing the decryption to fail. I know that RSA cannot encrypt data longer then the key size. Why it also fails when i try to decrypt 65 bytes of encrypted data with a 64 byte private key.